# Permission denied when compiling c++ project for android

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I have a c++ project that I compile with the ndk toolkit. Everything seems to build fine, but at the end of the build, when it want to output the dll is gives me this error

```
1>GCCCOMPILE : Fatal error : can't create c:/intermediate/Debug/Android/: Permission denied
```

However if I go to "C:/intermediate/Debug/Android/", the folder is created and I have some dll and log files that are outputted but not the dll of my project.

Any hints on this error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ndk-build V=1`, it will show all the compiler commands being used, which might help you determine the source of the error.

Does the folder have proper permissions for your user account to write to it?

Comment: Folder does have the proper permission settings... is it possible that my GCCCOMPILE doesn't have the right properties even if I run it as admin ?